# Worklight - intercepting HTTP requests to add a cookie

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on an Android app that is communicating with a Worklight server thanks to the Android SDK provided by Worklight.

I would like to integrate the AppConnect SDK (MDM) to the project in order to do some tunneling on communications. For this purpose, I have to add some AppConnect-related certificate configuration to an HTTP request.

The problem is that HttpURLConnections are encapsulated by the Worklight Android library. So I can't see the HttpURLConnections, and I can't add what I need to add to the requests...

That's why I would like to know : is it possible to overload the HTTP behavior of the Worklight Android library in this way ? And if it is possible, how can I do it ?

Comment: what version of worklight are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no such option provided by Worklight for Android. The used HttpClient is encapsulated inside the Worklight SDK code.

In order to support this functionality API methods for adding/removing 'request interceptors' will need to be provided.

You can submit a feature request, here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help/